# Return a value from callback which is situated in an async task doInBackGround

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, callback

I have the following bit of code:

here is a link to the doucmentation fo rthe asyncHttp:
[Link](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpResponseHandler.html#onSuccess%28int,%20org.apache.http.Header%5B%5D,%20byte%5B%5D%29)

This is what calls the login task:

```
mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask();
mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
```

Here is the async Task provided by android template activity:

```
    public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

        Network.login(mEmail, mPassword, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                    byte[] responseBody) {

                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    // Successfully got a response
                    for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
                        if (headers[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("token")) {
                            // Set the token to the received value
                            Network.SetToken(headers[i].getValue());
                    // >>>>>>>      return true;   <<<<<<<<<
                        }
                    }
                }
                // >>>>> return false  <<<<<<<<<<<<

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                    byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                // Response failed :(
                  //     >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> return false <<<<<<<<<<<<<
            }           
        });

        // TODO: register the new account here.
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);

        if (success) {
            finish();
        } else {
            mPasswordView
                    .setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
        }
    }
```

How can I return true or false from within my AsyncHttpResponseHandler and then return that value to the async task? So that it can then successfully execute its on post method.

I can only think of settings variable and then blocking on it. But then that defeatists the point of it being async and I would rather stay away from that.

Comment: And whats and where is the issue?

Comment: Isn't the `Network.login` async already with the `AsyncHttpResponseHandler`?

Comment: @super-qua Yes it is. But I dont think its on success method will run on the user thread will it? Because I have to update UI in my callback, and you are not allowed to update ui from a worker thread.

Comment: activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() { change your UI } } );

Comment: You could solve it the way @anthone mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the developer documents

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)

Now that said if you really want to finish in `onPostExecute` you can do this

```
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

        final ResponseContainer responseContainer = new ResponseContainer();
        Network.login(mEmail, mPassword, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                    byte[] responseBody) {

                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    // Successfully got a response
                    for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
                        if (headers[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("token")) {
                            // Set the token to the received value
                            Network.SetToken(headers[i].getValue());
                    // >>>>>>>      return true;   <<<<<<<<<
                            responseContainer.result = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // >>>>> return false  <<<<<<<<<<<<
                responseContainer.result = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                    byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                // Response failed :(
                  //     >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> return false <<<<<<<<<<<<<
                responseContainer.result = false;
            }           
        });

        // TODO: register the new account here.
        return responseContainer.result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);

        if (success) {
            finish();
        } else {
            mPasswordView
                    .setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    private class ResponseContainer {
        public boolean result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same question than the author, and I'm a bit sceptical about @Neil's answer. Using AsyncHttpResponseHandler (interface in general) will be executed asynchronously, so return responseContainer.result will be executed before onSuccess or onFailure. Right ? Or maybe it does but that would be unexpected! Thanks to clarify ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If, and only if, the Network call runs on it's own thread, you could try to do this by blocking `doInBackground` by figuring out which thread the network call uses and using [`Thread.join`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29).

However, I don't think you can guarantee it will, since you have not specified the executor and that can change outside the code you've given. So, if I had this issue, I would turn the code around and use an `AsyncHandler` to respond to the response of the Network call, avoiding nested async operations altogether. Something like this:

```
public void loginUser() {
    Network.login(mEmail, mPassword, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                byte[] responseBody) {

            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // Successfully got a response
                for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
                    if (headers[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("token")) {
                        // Set the token to the received value
                        Network.SetToken(headers[i].getValue());
                        new RegisterUserTask(statusCode, responseBody).execute();
                    }
                }
            }
            // respond to a failed authentication.
            mPasswordView
                .setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            // Response failed :(
              // Show some sort of error.
        }           
    });
}

public class RegisterUserTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    private int statusCode;
    private byte[] body;

    public RegisterUserTask(int statusCode, byte[] body) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.body = body;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO: register the new account here.

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);

        if (success) {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BUt will the ` public void onSuccess(` run on the user thread?

Comment: If we're talking about the `android-async-http` library, then yes. [From the docs (on the top of the page)](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/): *"All requests are made outside of your app’s main UI thread, but any callback logic will be executed on the same thread as the callback was created ..."*

Comment: Well in that case it is very easy. Thanks for confirming that

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the Network.login  already async?

You can use Handler system :

```
private static final int SUCCESS= 0;
private static final int FAIL= 1;
//In your class
    private final Handler handler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    switch (msg.what) {
                        case SUCCESS:
                            finish();
                            break;
                        case FAIL:
                            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
                            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

    public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

            Network.login(mEmail, mPassword, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                        byte[] responseBody) {

                    if (statusCode == 200) {
                        // Successfully got a response
                        for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
                            if (headers[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("token")) {
                                // Set the token to the received value
                                Network.SetToken(headers[i].getValue());
                                handler.sendEmptyMessage(SUCCESS);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // >>>>> return false  <<<<<<<<<<<<
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(FAIL);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                        byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                    // Response failed :(
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(FAIL);
                      //     >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> return false <<<<<<<<<<<<<
                }           
            });

            // TODO: register the new account here.
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

        }
    }
```

But I think you don't have to use the asyncTask with Network.login..
If it's synchrone maybe just a new Thread ?

```
new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Network.login(...) {
                       ...
                    }
                };
 }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get your point you mean finding a way to handle an event like AsyncTaskCompleted and do your staff there. The solution is  defining an interface like WebServiceCallbackProxy:

```
public interface WebServiceCallbackProxy {

    void CallBack(char[] jsonData, String serviceName, boolean isCommunicationSucceed, HttpRequestType reguestType, String serviceTicket);
}
```

Then define an instance in your AsyncTask:

```
public class AsynServiceCall extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, char[]> {

WebServiceCallbackProxy proxy;
.... 
public AsynServiceCall(WebServiceCallbackProxy webServiceProxy, ProgressDialog progressDialog) {
    this.proxy = webServiceProxy;

}
```

Then call your CallBackMethod on PostExecute:

```
protected void onPostExecute(char[] response) {
        if (this.progressDialog != null) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        if(proxy != null)
            proxy.CallBack(response, this.serviceName, this.isCommunicationSucced, this.requestType, this.serivceTicket);
    }
```

Doing so, you have an AsyncTask that has OnCompleted CallBack Method.